# Qt not receiving QWidget::dropEvent

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel

I drag a QStandardItem from a QListView over a QWidget.
In my QWidget class I implemented dragEnterEvent and dropEvent:

```
void MyWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event){
    qDebug() << "drag entering: ";
}

void MyWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event){
    qDebug() << "drop received!";
}
```

It receives the dragEntering, but not the dropping. 
I have already set the **acceptDrops** to true in the constructor of the QWidget class. What am I missing?
Thanks for help!

Comment: What is `MyWidget`?

Comment: MyWidget is just a class derived from QWidget

Comment: Can be possible that the drop event is called on the parent of your widget, i mean, the list or whatever `MyWidget` is in?

Comment: Oh, yes it is in a splitter... that could be the problem

Comment: Hm, setting acceptDrops of the splitter (and the mainWindow) to true didn't help. There must be something else I have to set up

Answer (score 2):

Well, I finally got the solution.
I had to add `event->acceptProposedAction();` in the dragEnterEvent in the widget class.

Comment: For me, I had to implement `void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)` and call `event->acceptProposedAction();` in there before I could get `dropEvent` to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of failure is an incorrect event type (copy and paste). Ensure they match the event handler:

```
dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
```