# How to enable drop from QTreeWidget to QML Map

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qml

I've the following class that contains a QML Map:

```
class MapWidget : public QQuickWidget {

  Q_OBJECT

public:

  MapWidget() = delete;
  MapWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
  MapWidget(const MapWidget&) = delete;
  MapWidget(MapWidget&&) = delete;
  ~MapWidget() = default;

public:

  MapWidget& operator=(const MapWidget&) = delete;
  MapWidget& operator=(MapWidget&&) = delete;

protected:

  void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* event) override;
  void dropEvent(QDropEvent* event) override;
};

//// .cpp ////

MapWidget::MapWidget(QWidget* parent) :
  QQuickWidget(parent) {
  setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/map.qml")));
  setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
  setAcceptDrops(true);
  QQuickItem* mapItem = dynamic_cast<QQuickItem*>(rootObject()->findChild<QQuickItem*>("myMap"));
  mapItem->setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// VIRTUAL PROTECTED SECTION                                                 //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void MapWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* event) {
  if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist")) {
    event->accept();
  }
  else {
    event->ignore();
  }
}

void MapWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent* event) {
  if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist")) {
    QGeoCoordinate returnedValue;
    auto pos = rootObject()->mapToScene(event->pos());
    QQuickItem* mapItem = dynamic_cast<QQuickItem*>(rootObject()->findChild<QQuickItem*>("myMap"));
    rootObject()->setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mapItem, "toCoordinate", Q_RETURN_ARG(QGeoCoordinate, returnedValue), Q_ARG(QPointF, pos));
    event->accept();
  }
  else {
    event->ignore();
  }
}
```

And this is the `map.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtPositioning 5.15
import QtLocation 5

Item {
    width: Qt.platform.os == "android" ? Screen.width : 512
    height: Qt.platform.os == "android" ? Screen.height : 512
    visible: true
    property double center_latitude: 59.91
    property double center_longitude: 10.75

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        objectName: "myMap"
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(center_latitude, center_longitude)
        zoomLevel: 14
        copyrightsVisible: false
    }
}
```

I can see the map. Next to it I've a `QTreeWidget` and I want to drag a `QTreeWidgetItem` into the map in order to create an item in the place where the mouse is placed.

With the debugger I can see that I enter in `dragEnterEvent` when I'm dragging the item inside the QML widget, but then when I release the mouse the `dropEvent` is not called. Also I can see in the widget the block sign, so it seems that the drop is not enabled in the map.

What I'm doing wrong and how can I enable the drop of a `QTreeWidgetItem` inside the map?

Comment: I see no usage of the `MapWidget` in your QML code.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43821

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from this [SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016790/qt-not-receiving-qwidgetdropevent#comment92510333_47022283). Basically you need to call either [accept](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qevent.html#accept) and/or [acceptProposedAction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdropevent.html#acceptProposedAction) in the `dragEnterEvent()` and `dragMoveEvent()`.

```
void MapWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << event->pos();
    event->accept();
}

void MapWidget::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << event->pos();
    event->accept();
}
```